# How to use increasing index value as a key to merge with a non-index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'subj_id': [11,12,13,14,15],
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('PPPS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWRR'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})

cdf = pd.DataFrame({'key_index': [1,1,1,3,3],
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('abcd'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('test'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((7890),size=(5))
})
```

As you can see that `cdf` contains it's index (also key) in a column called `key_index`. However, I have to merge these records with `tdf` to get the `subj_id` column.

Basically, `key_index = 1` in `cdf` corresponds to 2nd index row in `tdf`. `key_index = 3` corresponds to 4th index row in `tdf` etc. **`key_index + 1` in cdf always corresponds to = matching index position in `tdf`**

I tried the below but it doesn't work. I don't know how to add and scale this for million data rows

```
cdf.merge(tdf, right_index=True, left_index=False) #merge error
cdf.merge(tdf, right_index=False, left_index=True) #merge error
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `merge`, use `map` the single column you want atfer increasing the reference by 1:

```
cdf['subj_id'] = cdf['key_index'].add(1).map(tdf['subj_id'])
```

Output:

```
   key_index dash dumeel  dumma  subj_id
0          1    c      e    427       13
1          1    b      s   7090       13
2          1    d      t   4056       13
3          3    a      e   4186       15
4          3    b      s   1433       15
```

Alternative with `merge`:

```
cdf.merge(tdf['subj_id'],
          left_on=cdf['key_index'].add(1),
          right_index=True).drop(columns='key_0')
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. let me try. Let's say if I don't wish to add `1` to index, how would you usually merge based on `index` and `non-index` column? can include that option in your answer as well?

Comment: How would you match if you don't increase by 1? Note that here I am not modifying `tdf`'s index

Comment: because if both are index, I can use `left_index`, `right_index`. But since, one is a column (that dataframe already has another different index) and another merge key  is a index, i am not sure, how to merge

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. Check the update for a version with `merge`